# Angular 2 delaying elements rendering in loop

Tags: angular, delay, angular2-template

In my app I'm fetching some data from the API, data is basically just an array of objects, where each object is passed to prime-ng chart module. Code look like that:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">

  <div *ngFor="let set of chartdata" class="col col-12">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col col-6"><p-chart type="bar" [data]="set[0]['data']" [options]="set[0]['options']"></p-chart></div>
      <div class="col col-6"><p-chart type="bar" [data]="set[1]['data']" [options]="set[1]['options']"></p-chart></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

When `chartdata` array contains more than 4-6 elements, charts are not render smoothly, I would rather display one row with 2 charts at a time, and give it some millisecond for rendering before starting to render the next row with 2 charts.
Anyone know what is the best way to achieve this result ?

Comment: make use of `angular animations`

Comment: You can use a variable which set false initially and when all data came from api then  set it to true and use <div *ngIf="variable"> Your  *ngFor code </div>